# Converting a JavaScript(JS) file to TypeScript Definition file (.d.ts)

Tags: javascript, typescript, converters

I'm trying to convert the foundation.js file to typescript to use it in my project. I tried using the command

tsc -d foundation.ts --out foundation.js and alternatively tsc -d foundation.d.ts --out foundation.js

I'm getting an error.
"error TS5007: Cannot resolve referenced file: 'foundation.ts'."

Anyone solutions for this? or any other alternative to convert a .js to .d.ts file?

Comment: You can't just "convert" it to a TypeScript definition. http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#writing-dts-files

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create your own, there is one already created in the definitely typed repo... https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/foundation

You can get it multiple ways:

- clone the repo
- download the repo
- use [tsd](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd) ***recommended**
- use nuget (if you're using visual studio)